# My TCL script failed to evalue HTTP POST body response

Tags: http, post, web, tcl, fiddler

when i am using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) tool, I could able get HTTP POST body response,

```
HTTP/1.0 200 Ok
Server: xxxx TinyServer
MIME-version: 1.0
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache;
Pragma: no-cache;
Set-Cookie: session=0000743A; path=/;
Content-Type: text/xml
Expires: -1
Content-Length: 3509

<column><column_oid>1.3.6.1.4.1.664.5.63.900.1.20.17.1.1.1</column_oid><oid_value_pairs><![CDATA[1.3.6.1.4.1.664.5.63.900.1.20.17.1.1.1.4822:......
MORE....
```

But when i tried same HTTP POST operation using my TCL script, i am getting error message

```
set token [::http::geturl \
            "http://130.59.62.16/web/common/ajax/tcl/ajax_multi_get_xml.tcl" \
            -query "" -headers [array get Headers]]      

state(-keepalive)      = 0
state(-protocol)       = 1.1
state(-queryblocksize) = 8192
state(-queryprogress)  =
state(-strict)         = 1
state(-timeout)        = 0
state(-type)           = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
state(-validate)       = 0
state(binary)          = 0
state(body)            = <hr>
<pre><b>Session Variables:</b>


</pre><pre><b>Global Variables:</b>
base_oid = ""
rstr = ""


<b>Local Variables:</b>


</pre><hr>
can't read "oidlist": no such variable<br><b>from /web/common/ajax/tcl/ajax_multi_get_xml.tcl:8:</b><pre>
  1:
   2:    set rstr ""
   3:    if {[catch {set baseOID}] } {
   4:       set base_oid ""
   5:    } else {
   6:       set base_oid $baseOID
   7:    }
 <font color=red>  8:
 </font>  9:    snmp_getmulti $oidlist value err $count $base_oid
  10:    echo -n "<rvals>$value</rvals>"
  11: </pre>
```

Using Firefox Web Developer, When i moved the required page it was showing i was doing a POST Operation, please find below screenshot.

Here I don't have query filed in my POST operation, So i kept a blanks in my geturl. This type of URL how do i use query operation.

[image]

What was i missed between Fiddler tool and My script,
I could able to view using [Firefox Web Developer Console Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Accessing_variables)

Comment: What _exact_ headers are being sent by the browser? (And that `http::geturl` call is doing a GET, not a POST…)

Comment: If you want a **POST**, you need to supply the `-query` flag with `::http::geturl`, please see the documentation.

Comment: Thanks All, Please find above screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to debug this is to

1. Capture the working request from Fiddler
2. Use Fiddler to capture the non-working request from your TCL script
3. Select the working and not-working requests in Fiddler's Web Sessions list.
4. Right-click and choose "Compare Sessions."

Fiddler will show you how the two requests differ, so you can update your TCL script to send the proper request.